# Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't see Wacom Intuos

Tags: drivers, 16.04, wacom

I've tried to install a driver for wacom on Ubuntu 16.04 but it wouldn't work. The Wacom tablet is not detected by the system. What can I do for Ubuntu to see my tablet?

`xserver-xorg-input-wacom` is installed.
`libwacom2` and `libwacom-common` are installed too.

```
lsusb:


Bus 001 Device 008: ID 056a:033b Wacom Co., Ltd


xsetwacom --list devices:

Wacom Intuos S 2 Pen stylus         id: 10  type: STYLUS    
Wacom Intuos S 2 Pad pad            id: 11  type: PAD
```

But in system settings when opening Wacom Tablet section it shows **Tablet not detected**.

Comment: from what I can see your device should be supported, you might want to check out http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page and get a better resolution. it might give some better feedback.

Answer (score 1):

This is an active bug in `unity-control-center`: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1575887

Answer (score 1):

I was having huge problems with getting my Intuos 2 tablet to work. The settings section would see the tablet, it had power, it recognized the fact I was clicking, but the cursor would not move on the screen, basically the tablet was not there. None of those drivers available through the system worked, no matter what I did. I just managed to get my ancient (but much beloved and much used) digital pen working.

The system drivers just plain don't work. However if you compile from scratch
http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Input-wacom
and follow all instructions to the letter, you just might become very happy. I loaded the modules with the tablet plugged in and suddenly my touchpad started acting funny and I realized that the system finally recognized the pen. I own just a basic three-button pen, so not sure about any other pen tools like airbrush or something, but the basic pen works just fine now.

Hope this helps.